# Does strstr() return a pointer to malloced memory, requiring me to manually free it later?

Tags: c, malloc, strstr

I have a parser method that is parsing an API call. I am using `strstr()` in my parsing function.
My `parse_api` function is allowing me to return the pointer returned by `strstr`.
Am I correct in assuming that this means `strstr` mallocs a memory space and I need to free it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *parse_api(char *str);

int main() {
    char str[] = "dadsadsdsdsdamountdsafoodsd";
    puts(parse_api(str));
    return 0;
}
  
char *parse_api(char *str) {
    char *needle;
    char *updated_needle;
    needle = strstr(str, "amount");
    puts(needle);
    updated_needle = needle + 9;
    updated_needle[strlen(updated_needle) - 3] = '\0';
    return updated_needle;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strstr` function does *not* return alloc'ed memory.  It returns a pointer to the start of the substring inside of the `haystack` parameter.

So in this case `strstr` will return `str + 12`.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation, [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) the following describes the returned value:

> Pointer to the first character of the found substring in `str`, or a null pointer if such substring is not found. If `substr` points to an empty string, `str` is returned.

When it says it returns a pointer to the first character of the substring, it means that quite literally. It points to a location within `str`. In your case, it returns `str + 12`. No memory is allocated.

Note: This means that the value returned by `strstr` stops being valid if `str` is changed or freed!

Comment: *if str is changed or freed!* or if it goes out of scope.

Comment: @chqrlie, You appear to be talking about a variable with automatic storage going out of scope. Such variables are *auto*matically freed when they go out of scope. So like I said, when the string is changed of freed.

Comment: I find it rather confusing to use the word `free` for objects going out of scope where essentially no code is involved in their dismissal. Newbies are likely to assume that the compiler issues calls to `free()` behind the scenes. Discarded would be more appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @chqrlie, How newbies suspect something works is not really a major concern when it's inconsequential and addressing it would complicate a far more important issue. The concept that automatic storage variable only exists while in scope is far more important for them to get right. Going into the details about the mechanism by which that is achieved --especially when the standard makes no guarantee about it-- only detracts.